# Communicate with node.js from VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, node.js, websocket

I have a node.js-app running on the same machine on port 8080 with different channels. The communication between my jQuery-site and my .NET endpoint works perfectly.

My Site:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>WebSocket-Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('button').click(function() {
                    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');
                    socket.on($('#username').val(), function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        socket.emit('my other event', { my: data });
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
        <input type="text" id="username" />
        <button>connect</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

My node.js-server:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(4000);
var count = 0;

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    setInterval(function () {
        socket.emit('daniel', { hello: 'Waited two seconds!'});
    }, 2000);
    socket.emit('daniel', { hello: 'world' });  
    socket.emit('stefan', { hello: 'world2' });  
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

My question is, how can I emmit a message from my .NET backend via node.js?

After my page is loaded I do have a window.io-object. What is the best approach? Just do an eval on the io-object with emmit and the channel or can I pass an object or json-thing to my node.js-server?

My target is, to send an event-driven message. When a new row is inserted into my MSQL-DB a message should be send to the channels.

Comment: Just by the way. StackOverflow allows you to post code directly, inclusive code highlightning. (This make testing something easier because you can copy and paste what was asked.)

Comment: Were you planning on having .NET poll the DB to publish the events? And are the insertions happening from other sources? Also, this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12867731/945456) might help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that you can do, is simply ping the Node.js server when there's an update with the details. You can do this over straight http/https.

Basically, when .NET updates the db, it can fire off a quick POST to a node.js endpoint with the data package that you want to roll out to users.